# What if a member of a variable is trying to delete the variable? Will the member still exist?

Tags: oop, object, computer-science

I've been confused by this question for a long time and I don't know which field of computer science does the question belong to.

To be more specific, let's say we have a variable `a` and it's an object. `b` is a member of `a` and it's also an object.

What if `b` has a method which could destroy `a`? Can this happen? If it can, does `b` still exist after `a` is destroyed?

I think this issue is different from **a leaf node is trying to delete its parent node.**

Is the result varies with the language?

I feel sorry if the description is not clear enough because I haven't really meet a real case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends a lot on the language.

I think most languages do not let you explicitly destroy an object, so this situation cannot happen.

In many languages (e.g. Java, Perl, JavaScript, Python, ...), objects are destroyed by the garbage collector when the program can no longer access them, and objects are inherently references, i.e. `a` having a member `b` simply means `a` keeps a reference to `b`, so if `a` goes away, nothing happens to `b` (as long as you still have some other reference to `b`).

In a language like C++, you can explicitly destroy objects. What happens then depends on other details: If `b` is a direct member of `a`, then `b` is destroyed along with `a` (and if you still have a pointer or reference to `b`, it becomes "dangling", i.e. it is an error to try to access it). On the other hand, if `b` is merely pointed to or referenced from `a`, then it stays alive.

Comment: Thanks. As I want to go further on this issue, what kind of materials should I refer to? Compilers? (I don't major in CS, but I want to learn more about this)